# Ударение в слове

Tags: ударение

Является ли верным такое ударение: проЯснится (сделается ясным)? Услышала сегодня впервые в телевизионной передаче от ведущего.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В настоящее время глаголы прояснИть, прояснИться имеют ударение на суффиксе в двух основных значения: 1)сделать/сделаться понятным; 2) сделать/сделаться безоблачным (о погоде).

Тем не менее, в орфоэпическом словаре отмечаются варианты с двумя ударениями (для погоды): проЯснеть,проЯснить, проЯсниться и прояснИться: К вечеру проЯснело (проЯснилось и прояснИлось).

В поэтических текстах такое "погодное" ударение может использоваться в переносном смысле: 
"Мой мозг проЯснили дурманы,Душа влечется в примитив.Я вижу росные туманы!Я слышу липовый мотив!" (И. Северянин).

"И когда на проЯсневшей глади равнин Все полягут, как новые горы, В Средиземное море уходит хамсин Кровь дурманить и сеять раздоры" (Н. Гумилев).

Галчонком глянет Рождество, И разгулявшийся денек ПроЯснит много из того, Что мне и милой невдомек (Б. Пастернак).

Comment: Спасибо. У Диброва "проЯснится" прозвучало в значении "станет понятным".

Comment: Наверное, у Диброва такое образно-поэтическое восприятие мира. А может быть, народно-просторечное. Надо биографию изучать.

Answer (score 4):

Сделал выписку из Словаря 1847 :
"ПроЯснивать(ся) (прояснЕть/прояснИться) ... становиться яснее, светлеть. *Небо начинает проЯснивать*.
Таким образом, ударение на Я (было) принято в глагольных формах с суффиксом *ива*, в целях благозвучия.
*ПроЯснится* - очевидно, просторечие.

Answer (score 2):

А в орфографическом словаре под под редакцией Лопатина дается два варианта: проЯсниться, -ится (о погоде)

прояснИться, -нится (сделаться ясным, четким, понятным)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что верным является ударение на гласный *И*.